# phonegap/webview apps and background services

Tags: android, android-intent, cordova

I hope this question meets the criteria for the site. I'll happily update otherwise.

I am, like many others, developing an application for multiple platforms using the PhoneGap (in this case Cordova 3) framework and want to keep my application alive while the use performs others tasks. I have read around this subject and seem many opinions and possible/partial solutions.

Notionally, what I want to do is allow the user to return to the application had they pressed back, home, they got a phone call, they played tetris or whatever and specifically if the app wants them back under certain conditions.

I am presently tackling this by concentrating on the Android platform and will expand out after this solved. I understand the mechanism by which Android OS will kill processes that are not visible and understand and have implemented an example background service.

I employ JQuery Mobile with collapsible content for my application.

Before I continue development, I would like to ensure I am on the right path.

I have successfully implemented pause/resume to handle phone locking and sleep. My application does not die and I can make it beep and vibrate through appropriate plugins.

My continued intention is this ...

Write a background service to perform periodic "checks" in this case position of phone relative to a known position. The intention is to inform the user when they have reached certain proximity. This would be started on the "pause" event and stopped on the "resume" or of the app is restarted.

Using Local Storage, maintain a record of state of the UI so it can be restarted in the correct state. Upon restart, the stored state will be restored and the app will look like it never went away. There is nothing in the app which continuously updates, like graphics or logs, so there is no reason to retrieve "past states" from the background service and perform a rendering of those as if they had been performed by the app, but that would not seem unreasonable should that be required on the future.

As it's possible that the app will not be running, it seems necessary for the service to create a ("something important has happened") notification that the user can click on in order to restart the application. I have found a couple of status bar notification plugins and intend to use one. I trust I will be able to beep/vibrate accordingly from the background service alo.

In addition, a "stuff is generally happening" continuous notification could be used to restart the app. I see no conflict with the above. It would be nice to find a "bring app to foreground is it's running" method, but I'm holding out no hope.

My essential question is this ...

Am I approaching this problem correctly and maintaining as much cross platform work as possible whilst not setting myself up for a fall when it comes to implementing the iOS facet of the solution?

I just don't want to miss a trick I've not located in the sea of answers to what seems like a common problem.